# Reaching an Angular application served on a docker proxied through nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a VirtualBox with a docker-compose configured to launch an Angular application and nginx to solve a port-collision with another application (out of the scope of the question).
I can correctly reach the application in the hosting machine (through http://localhost:90/angularApp), but I can't correctly reach from an external machine since angular can't correctly find the static files it needs.

I tried playing with various settings in the nginx's development.conf (since I suppose that's where I have to correctly configure the environment) and the angular 'serve' paramenters (mostly 'baseHref'), but either the application would work only through localhost:4200 (native angular) and localhost:90/angularApp (nginx proxy), or only through the first one.

I also tried some google-fu, but found nothing that could help with this mix of docker environment and re-routing

Here are my config files:

#### project/docker/angular/DockerFile

```
FROM node:12.2.0

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

#### project/docker/nginx/development.conf

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             nginx;

    proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;

    location /angularApp {
        proxy_pass   http://myApplication:4200/;
    }
}
```

#### project/docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "90:80"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - back

  myApplication:
    build: ./docker/angular/
    command: bash -c "npm i && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --baseHref http://localhost:90/angularApp/" <-- I know this can't work when I'd access from another machine
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./myApplication:/app    
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    networks:
      - back

networks:
  back:    
    driver: bridge
```

The main error is that when location is set as "/angularApp" [hostIp]:90/angularApp can't find its own static files (`GET http://localhost:90/angularApp/runtime.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED angularApp:11`), while access from the guest machine works fine, but I don't understand what should I use in `baseHref` and in the nginx's location configuration to make myApplication accessible from the outside.

In case I'd have to use the `root` configuration in nginx's location I can't use absolute paths since it's a shared project.

(I also know that the most straightforward workaround would be to redirect all localhost request to the remote machine since it's a VM in my own machine, but it seemed to me a dirty trick)

Comment: I don't know much about nginx  but I think you should access your application as the same for any environment. So I would try that as well
`location /angularApp {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:90/angularApp/
} `

and 

`--baseHref http://localhost:90/angularApp/" `

Comment: That's the problem; when from the VM I try to access localhost:90, it works since localhost:90 is correctly routed inside the VM. If I try to access localhost:90 from OUTSIDE the VM, that path is not routed and results in a 404

Comment: `ports:
      - "4200:90"` try to add this as well to your compose yml

Comment: and then from outside of VM http://localhost:4200/angularApp should work

Comment: I can't have a "localhost" reference from outside, since I would want to connect to the guest machine from another machine, that's why I wrote that the baseHref is wrong